# SQL replace all specified keys

Tags: mysql, sql, json, regex, replace

I have one column(varchar) containing only json string within one table. I want replace all keys with "" on that column. How can I do that using sql? My database is MySQL.

For example:

```
|--------------------------------------------------------------------|
|                            t_column                                |                  
|--------------------------------------------------------------------|
| {"name":"mike","email":"xxx@example.com","isManage":false,"age":22}|
|--------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

```sql
SELECT replace(t_column, regexp, "") FROM t_table
```

I expect:
`mikexxx@example.comfalse22`

How to write that `regexp`?

Comment: Why aren't you using the JSON type?

Comment: Because I want search keyword based value of JSON and validate whether that keyword exists in the value of JSON. But I don't know how many keys does that JSON has since every record has different type of JSON form.

Comment: Are name, email, isManage and age the only keys?

Comment: no, I have different JSON form in that column.

Comment: What is the use case for building a combined unstructured string?

Comment: I want to validate whether a keyword is contained on a value of JSON or not. But the keyword may also be contained on the key of that JSON. I just want validate the value of JSON instead of key.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to solve the problem with your approach then the question becomes

*What is the regex that **selects all the undesired text** from the string `{"name":"mike","email":"xxx@example.com","isManage":false,"age":22}` ?*

Then the answer would be: `{\"name\":\"|\"email\":\"|\",\"isManage\":|,\"age\":|}`

But as others let you notice I would actually approach the problem parsing JSONs. Look up for [functions json_value and json_query](https://database.guide/json_query-vs-json_value-in-sql-server-whats-the-difference/)

Hope I helped

*PS: Keep close attention on how I structured the bolded sentence. Any difference changes the problem.*

**EDIT**:
If you want a more generic expression, something like ***select all the text that is not a value on a json-formatted string***, you can use this one:

`{|",|"\w+\":|"|,|}`

Comment: Thank for your reply. I have many kinds of json form instead of this one. Therefore your regex doesn't match all case.

Answer (score 0):

Start from

```
select t_column->'$.*' from test
```

This will return a JSON array of attribute values:

```
[22, "mike", "xxx@example.com", false]
```

This might be already all you need, and you can try something like

```
select *
from test
where t_column->'$.*' like '%mike%';
```

Unfortunately there seems to be no native way to join array values to a single string like `JSON_ARRAY_CONCAT()`. In MySQL 8.0 you can try `REGEXP_REPLACE()` and strip all JSON characters:

```
select regexp_replace(t_column->'$.*', '[" ,\\[\\]]', '') from test
```

which will return `'22mikexxx@example.comfalse'`.

If the values can contain one of those characters, they will also be removed.

Note: That isn't very reliable. But it's all I can do in a "simple" way.

See demo on [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2fxK5jyukaasynMe4zMDwv/0).

Answer (score 0):

I could be making it too simplistic, but this is just a mockup based on your comment. I can formalize it into a query if it fits your requirement.

Let's say you get your JSON string to this format where you replace all the double quotes and curly brackets and then add a comma at the end. After playing with `replace` and `concat_ws`, you are now left with:

name:mike,email:xxx@example.com,isManage:false,age:22,

With this format, every value is now preceded by a semicolon and followed by a comma, which is not true for the key. Let's say you now want to see if this JSON string has the value "mike" in it. This, you could achieve using

```
select * from your_table where json_col like '%:mike,%';
```